# what is 1..n, ?..m and these symbols in ERD?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I'm new to ERD, I know 1:1 means one to one. 
1:n one to many. 
m:1 many to one. 
m:n many to many

but what are these symbols mean is ERD?
image from "software idea modeler v11.55": http://s8.picofile.com/file/8326381876/Capture.JPG
[image: here are symbols]

Answer (score 1):

*n* means *exactly number*

You can replace n with any number needed for your database model.

read more about this cheatsheet: http://www.32geeks.com/classes/resources/IDEF1X_Cheat_Sheet.pdf